# How to extract data from a website like justdial using beautiful soup python which has a very large list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup to extract Ngo Information from justdial.com I am able to get the data. But the problem is it is fetching only initial 10 items. When scrolling manually on their website I was able to get around 324 ngos. I have used the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

#url to fetch
url="http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/ngos"
req = requests.get(url)

#Get the data from the requested source
data=req.text

#use Beautiful Soup to get data from the website
soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
```

But this returns only 9 items. How to get all the items?

Comment: Beautifulsoup extracts the contents from an HTML page. Apparently Justdial returns only 9 items when you load the page - and later this javascript page pulls the contents and adds to the page. Beautifulsoup won't help here. Try mechanize or selenium

Comment: I made something that could solve this - https://rapidapi.com/sameer.kumar/api/justdial-jd-unofficial

Answer (score 1):

As Rob says, the page uses JavaScript to load more NGO's when you scroll down. This doesn't happen when you fetch the html using requests. You have two options:

1. Go manually to the page, scroll down as far as you can and then view the html source of the page and scrape that. You can't do this if you need to extract hundreds of pages of course.
2. Dig into the page source to find out where it gets the 10 additional pages from. You can do this in chrome with the developer tools (under the network tab). There, I did it for you, it is using this url: http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Bangalore&search=Ngos&where=&catid=232578&psearch=&prid=&page=4 See if you can do something with that.

Answer (score 0):

That is because, if you look at what is happening, the site loads more as you scroll. If you can find where they are making the AJAX call (presumably in Javascript), I would recommend imitating the call that is loading the additional data.

This will have the added benefit of letting you get the data directly, without dealing with the middleman of the web page, and you will likely be able to get as much data as you please.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this jusr dail scraper](https://github.com/harsh4870/Justdail-scrapper) i have written it simple update the URL and inside the code and run the code it will work to extract the data.

Answer (score -1):

in console of browser I founded: 
http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Bangalore&search=Ngos&where=&catid=232578&psearch=&prid=&page=2

I think you can just parse this url by pages
http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Bangalore&search=Ngos&where=&catid=232578&psearch=&prid=&page=3
http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Bangalore&search=Ngos&where=&catid=232578&psearch=&prid=&page=4

and e.t.c